# How to fix LSTM Layer Error - Image Classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm, keras-layer

Currently I'm working on an image classification issue and created the following code based on a tutorial online - [Image Classification using Keras](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-image-classification-using-keras/).

The code works fine, but when addind the LSTM layer it has problems with the input_shape and I'm unable to figure out the solution:

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4

The code:

```
img_width, img_height = 224, 135
train_dir = './train'
test_dir = './test'
train_samples = 46822
test_samples = 8994
epochs = 25
batch_size = 16

input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 3)

model = Sequential() 
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape = input_shape, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(LSTM(3, return_sequences=True, input_shape = input_shape))
model.add(AveragePooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 128, activation = 'softmax'))

model.compile(loss ='categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer ='adam', 
              metrics =['accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator( 
            rescale = 1. / 255, 
            shear_range = 0.2, 
            zoom_range = 0.2, 
        horizontal_flip = True) 

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1. / 255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_dir, target_size =(img_width, img_height), batch_size = batch_size, class_mode ='categorical')

validation_generator = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(test_dir, target_size =(img_width, img_height), batch_size = batch_size, class_mode ='categorical') 

model.fit_generator(train_generator, 
    steps_per_epoch = train_samples // batch_size, 
    epochs = epochs, validation_data = validation_generator, 
    validation_steps = test_samples // batch_size)
```

Extra info:

The size of input_shape = (224,135,3)

In the train and test folder are each 3 sub folders that contains a set of images based on Human Movements sequences.

The mentioned error does provide some Google results, but those didn't provide a solution in my case --> I've tried changing the input_shape for the LSTM layer to various options like (224,3) or any variant, etc.

I'm probably overseeing one stupid thing and hope someone here might have an idea?

Answer (score 0):

Add `TimeDistributed(Flatten())` layer before the LSTM layer.